# find and negation of an -iname condition

Tags: find

I am trying to find all the files which have 'pillar' in the name (case incentive) and do not contain 'cache' (also case insensitive) with

```
find . -iname '*pillar*' -and -not -iname '*cache*'
```

but it not working as I find (among others)

```
./Caches/Metadata/Safari/History/https:%2F%2Fwww.google.ch%2Fsearch?q=pillars+of+eternity+dropbox&client=safari&rls=en&biw=1440&bih=726&ei=CnBDVbhXxulSnLaBwAk&start=10&sa=N%23.webhistory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you want to avoid looking for files in `*cache*` directories more than finding files with `*pillar*` and not `*cache*` in their name. Then, just tell `find` not to bother descending into `*cache*` directories:

```
find . -iname '*cache*' -prune -o -iname '*pillar*' -print
```

Or with `zsh -o extendedglob`:

```
ls -ld -- (#i)(^*cache*/)#*pillar*
```

(not strictly equivalent as that would report a `foo/pillar-cache` file)

Or (less efficient as it descends the whole tree like in [@apaul's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208705)):

```
ls -ld -- (#i)**/*pillar*~*cache*
```

Details on the `zsh` specific globs:

- `(#i)`: turn on case insensitive matching
- `^`: negation glob operator
- `(...)`: grouping (like `@(...)` in `ksh`).
- `<something>#`: zero or more of `<something>` (like `*` in regexps).
- `~`: and-not operator (matches on the whole path)
- `**/`: 0 or more directory levels (short for `(*/)#`).

Add the `(D)` glob qualifier if you want to descend into hidden dires and match hidden files like in the `find` solution.

Answer (score 8):

The `find` options you've specified apply on the filename, not on the name of sub-directories.

Here, your filename doesn't contain `cache` but contains `pillar`, so it matches.

In your case, you may want to use the `-path` option. Something like:

```
find . -iname '*pillar*' -and -not -ipath '*cache*'
```